# Weird issue with await operator

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, async-await

I had a weird problem today...
My code is running stuck on the await method in c# (no error or sth).

```
user = await JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<User>(content);
```

but when i remove the "await" my code works...

```
user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<User>(content).Result;
```

I have the same problem with my HttpClient:

**Works**

```
using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(url, posts).Result)
```

**Doesn't work**

```
using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, posts))
```

the problem wasn't there the day before and if i place my code in another class it works properly

output:

```
The thread 0xe44 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x81c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x150c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1660 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
```

I rebuilded and I have still that problem.

Does someone know the answer?

Comment: Are you running on the UI thread? Is the UI thread blocked waiting for something else?

Comment: Note that those functions shouldn't exist in the first place; you should explicitly leave the UI thread higher-up using `Task.Run()`. https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/66 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx

Comment: Ow I see now, I had to call my function from my UI with the await operator

Comment: Wrong.  You can `await` on any thread.

Comment: Yes I didn't leave the UI thread, that was my problem :D Sorry for this stupid question but thanks a lot for the answer it solved my problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are running into a [common deadlock issue](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) that I describe on my blog.

To solve it, use `await` all the way; remove any `Task.Wait` or `Task<T>.Result` calls from your code.